# Running "taco create" fails with "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Tags: taco

New to TACO and I'm following the [Getting Started with TACO-CLI](http://taco.tools/docs/getting-started.html). Sadly I am getting an error when running this create command:

```
taco create hello
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
$ taco create hello

Downloading: taco-kits
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\taco-kits\latest\package.json'
npm WARN latest No description
npm WARN latest No repository field.
npm WARN latest No README data
npm WARN latest No license field.

taco-kits downloaded and installed.
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\taco-kits\latest\node_modules\taco-kits'
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I have these versions of stuff:

```
 npm 3.9.6
 taco 1.2.1
 node 6.2.1
 Windows 10 (latest updates)
```

I've also tried with the latest stable version of node (4.4.5) and no joy.

Indeed, the contents of 'C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\taco-kits\latest\'  does not contain a package.json file. Here's what I see there:

```
node_modules
timestamp.txt
```

The 'C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\taco-kits\latest\node_modules\taco-kits' contains this:

```
LICENSE
TacoKitMetadata.json
node_modules
package.json
resources
tacoErrorCodes.js
tacoErrorHelper.js
tacoKits.js
templates
test
```

The package.json file in that folder contains the following:

```
{
  "name": "taco-kits",
  "description": "Validated Kits metadata for taco CLI",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "author": {
    "name": "Microsoft Corporation",
    "email": "vscordovatools-admin@microsoft.com"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Microsoft/TACO.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Microsoft/TACO/issues",
    "email": "vscordovatools-admin@microsoft.com"
  },
  "homepage": "http://taco.tools",
  "main": "tacoKits.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "coverage": "istanbul cover --report json node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- --reporter spec"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "q": "^1.1.2",
    "taco-utils": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "2.0.1",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.0",
    "should": "4.3.0",
    "taco-tests-utils": "^0.1.4"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "_id": "taco-kits@1.2.0",
  "_shasum": "7e9281a34e59cfb64234057e6ada10a99791a6ef",
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/taco-kits/-/taco-kits-1.2.0.tgz",
  "_from": "taco-kits@latest",
  "_npmVersion": "2.14.9",
  "_nodeVersion": "0.12.9",
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "vsmobile",
    "email": "vscordovatools-admin@microsoft.com"
  },
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "7e9281a34e59cfb64234057e6ada10a99791a6ef",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/taco-kits/-/taco-kits-1.2.0.tgz"
  },
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "vsmobile",
      "email": "vscordovatools-admin@microsoft.com"
    }
  ],
  "directories": {}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update (resolved)**

I was able to resolve this issue by deleting the taco-kits folder and then running *taco kit list* which reinstalled the kits. The bash commands I used are as follows (using bash):

```
rm -Rf /c/users/kyle/AppData/Roaming/taco_home/node_modules/taco-kits/ 
taco kit list
```

I'd suggest just renaming that taco-kits folder first just to make sure it works for you.

Comment: Resolved: See my updates at the end for a possible resolution.